# Using Linq to Get a List of Objects to a Distinct Grouped List

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a list of this object returned in a working API at the moment.

```cs
    public class ShoppingListItemDto
    {
        public int ShoppingListItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get it into a grouped list object. Something like this:

```cs
    public class GroupedShoppingListItemDto
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<ShoppingListItemDto> ShoppingListItemDto { get; set; }
    }
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq) and put together the below, but I can't seem to get it to pull in the nested objects.

```cs
var list = _context.ShoppingListItems                
                .GroupBy(sli => new { sli.Category })
                     .Select(sli => new GroupedShoppingListItemDto { }).ToList();
```

For example, I'd like the linq query to return something like this:

```
{
    "category":"produce",
    "items": [
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"lettuce",
            "category":"produce"
        },
        {
            "id":4,
            "name":"cucumber",
            "category":"produce"
        }       
    ],
    "category":"meat",
    "items": [
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"chicken",
            "category":"meat"
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "name":"steak",
            "category":"meat"
        }       
    ]
}
```

Comment: `.Select(sli => new GroupedShoppingListItemDto { Category = sli.Key, ShoppingListItemDto = sli.ToList() }).ToList()` ?

Comment: Doesn't look like i can do `sli.ToList()` here

Comment: you can call `ToList()` to fetch all records from EF, and then do grouping. Like: `_context.ShoppingListItems.ToList().GroupBy(sli => sli.Category).Select(g => new GroupedShoppingListItemDto { ... }).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `ToList` on `Select` query.

```
var newList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
.Select(x => new GroupedShoppingListItemDto { Category = x.Key, ShoppingListItemDto = x.ToList() });
```

It's should works

Comment: gives me an error: (The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue<string>(grouping.Key, 0, Property: ShoppingListItem.Category (string)), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: ShoppingListItem
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)
    .ToList()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable()...

Comment: Try using AsEnumerable() before groupBy (list.AsEnumerable()), suggested solution will work. From exception it is clear that EF is not able to translate the query.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of ShoppingListItems and every ShoppingListItem has a Category, which is a string. Some `ShoppingListItems` have the same Category.

You want to make groups of ShoppingListItems that have the same Category. You are right, for this you need to use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1).

You want to have a specific output format. In that case, use the GroupBy with a parameter ResultSelector:

```
var result = _context.ShoppingListItems.GroupBy(
    // parameter KeySelector: make groups of ShopplingListitems with same Category               
    shoppingListItem => shoppingListItem.Category,

    // parameter ResultSelector: for every category, and all ShoppingListItems
    // with this category make one new GroupedShoppingListItemDto
    (category, shoppingListItemsWithThisCategory) => new GroupedShoppingListItemDto
    {
        Category = category,
        ShoppingListItems = shoppingListItemsWithThisCategory.ToList(),
    })

    // execute the query:
    .ToList();
```

Note, that every ShoppingListItem in your GroupedShoppingListItemDto will have a Category of which you already know the value: it equals GroupedShoppingListItemDto.Category. If you have a 1000 ShoppingListItems with category "meat", you will transfer this same value more than a 1000 times, which is quite a waste of processing power.

Therefore, if you will only use the result locally within this procedure, consider using anonymous types:

```
var result = _context.ShoppingListItems.GroupBy(shoppingListItem => shoppingListItem.Category,

(category, shoppingListItemsWithThisCategory) => new
{
    Category = category,
    ShoppingListItems = shoppingListItemsWithThisCategory.Select(shoppingListItem => new
    {
        // Select only the properties that you plan to use:
        Id = shoppingListItem.Id,
        Name = shoppingListItem.Name,
        ...

        // No need to select, you already know the value
        // Category = shoppingListItem.Category
})
```